# For given prime number $p \neq 2$, construct a non-Abelian group with exponent $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For given prime number $p \neq 2$, construct a non-Abelian group with exponent $p$.

We know that for $p=2$ it's impossible.

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 7):

For $p>2$, take the set of upper-triangular $3\times 3$ matrices with elements from the field with $p$-elements and $1$s on the diagonal. This has exponent $p$ (why?), order $p^3$ (why?) and has centre of order $p$ (so is non-abelian). To check that the centre has order $p$, you should prove that a group of order $p^3$ has centre of order $p^3$ or of order $p$ and then show that the group is non-abelian. This group is called the *[Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$*

Note that for $p=2$, this group has exponent four. Look up the classification of Extra-Special $p$-groups for more details about these groups.

For example, take $p=3$. Then this group has the following presentation. $$\langle x,y,z; x^3 = y^3 = z^3 = 1, yz = zyx, xy = yx, xz = zx\rangle$$ The group has order $27$ and has exponent three. Clearly it is non-abelian (as otherwise $x=1$ and the group is simply the non-cyclic abelian group of order nine. Which it isn't.). For other primes $p>2$, change each of the three $3$s in the presentation to a $p$.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting construction!

Comment: You're welcome - I read it in a book a long time ago! It is the smallest example, in the sense that it cannot happen for $p^2$ (why?) and by the classification of Extra-Special $p$-groups, this is the only example for $p^3$.