# Law of Exponents for Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of an Abelian group and let $n$ be any positive integer. Show that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$. Is this also true for non-Abelian groups?

Comment: You definitely need to use the fact that the group is abelian in order to successfully write the proof. Since commutativity is a necessary condition to successfully prove $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, we cannot generalize to non-abelian groups.

Comment: No! You cannot rewrite $(ab)^n=ababab...ab$ as $a^nb^n$ unless you can interchange $a$'s and $b$'s.

Answer (score 2):

This is never true for non-abelian groups if $n=2$, but otherwise, for $n\ge 3$ this can happen for certain non-abelian groups. For more details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053168/when-does-abn-an-bn-imply-a-group-is-abelian).
Example: The quaternion group satisfies $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all $n=2^k$ with $k>1$, but is not abelian.

Comment: Also, as a consequence of Lagrange's theorem we have the fairly trivial result that if $G$ is a finite group then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ whenever $|G| \mid n$

Answer (score 0):

$(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all $n$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ commute with each other. For example, if $a=e$, or $a=b$. Also, if $b=a^{-1}$. And for another example, if $a$ is in the center of $G$, then $a$ commutes with every element of $G$, so it commutes with $b$.

Edit: If you mean for a specific $n$ as opposed to all positive integers $n$, then see @Dietrich Burde's answer.

Comment: The OP did not say *for all* $n$.

Comment: True, he did say "let $n$ be any positive integer." I didn't read that carefully enough.

Comment: Well, the formulation "is this also true for non-Abelian groups" is not so clear. For your interpretation, see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers/41004#41004).