# If $(ab)^k = a^k b^k$ for two consecutives integers $k$, is $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Suppose $G$ is a group such that there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $(ab)^k = a^k b^k$ and $(ab)^{k+1} = a^{k+1} b^{k+1}$.
>
> Is $G$ abelian?

I've tried to use the same argument in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers) post, but it doesn't work.

Is there a non-abelian group $G$ with this property?

Comment: What if the exponent of $G$ is $k$?

Comment: Take $k = |G|$...

Comment: @lhf The question nowhere says or suggests that $G$ is finite.

Comment: Is $k=0$ admissible?

Comment: Sure $k=0$ is admissible! And it works for all group... Nice!
Such a dumb question I've made.

Comment: While $0\in\Bbb N$ still raises some debate, I don't think anybody really contests $0\in\Bbb Z$. Since we get no information from that case, the answer must obviously be "not necessarily" (and "yes, _all_ non-abelian groups do satisfy the hypothesis").

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199479/non-abelian-group-g-satisfying-a-cdot-bi-ai-cdot-bi-for-two-consecut and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103124/an-example-of-a-non-abelian-group-g-where-for-all-a-b-in-g-the-equality. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467323/non-abelian-groups-where-abni-anibni-for-all-0-leq-i-leq-k-k.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume that the $k=0$ isn't allowed.

As given in the comments above, say that $k = \lvert G\rvert$. Then for any $g\in G$, $g^k = e$ (identity in $G$). In particular $(ab)^k = e$ for all $a,b\in G$. In this case

$$
(ab)^k = e = a^kb^k
$$
and
$$
(ab)^{k+1} = (ab)^kab = eab = ab \\
a^{k+1}b^{k+1} = a^kab^kb = eaeb= ab
$$
So in fact, for all finite groups (even the non Abelian ones) $G$ there is indeed a $k$ such that
$$
(ab)^k = a^k b^k$$ 
and 
$$
(ab)^{k+1} = a^{k+1} b^{k+1}
$$

---

Just for fun, think about the case where there is a $k\neq 0$ not a multiple of $\lvert G\rvert$ such that \dots

Comment: $G$ isn't necessarily finite though, at least not in the question posed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why this argument doesn't work for the case in the post that I've related..

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht: Right, the question is if you can conclude that $G$ is Abelian. The answer is that you can't conclude this because there are groups that satisfy the equations while not being Abelian. Here is *another* question: Are there any infinite non-Abelian groups satisfying the equations?

Comment: @rldias: Because in that post you assume one extra equation $(ab)^{k+2} = a^{k+2}b^{k+2}$ (the three consecutive integers thing.)

Comment: For every group $G$, it is true that $(ab)^0 = a^0 b^0$ and $(ab)^1 = a^1 b^1$ for all $a,b\in G$. Just take $k=0$ and conclude that my question was horrible.

Comment: @rldias: Yeah, I see that now. I will keep my answer since it might be interesting to you with the condition that $k\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

$k=0$ works for all groups, even infinite nonabelian ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following property :$G$ be a group and $k$ be a integer having the property that $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ and $(ab)^{k+1}=a^{k+1}b^{k+1}$ then
$G$ is abelian iff $(ab)^{k+2}=a^{k+2}b^{k+2}$.