# Counterexample for group having following property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know following 
G is group in which $a^ib^i=(ab)^i$ this hold for consecutive 3 integer then it is abelian .
I can prove this fact.
I know that this is not true in case of 2 consecutive integer.I searched for example but I am not getting .
Any Help will be appreciated .
Thanks 
Note: Similar question will be here [An example of a non-abelian group $G$ where, for all $a,b\in G$, the equality $(ab)^{n}=a^{n}b^{n}$ holds for two consecutive integers $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103124/an-example-of-a-non-abelian-group-g-where-for-all-a-b-in-g-the-equality) with answer
But I know trivially for 0 ,1 integer will work But  I am searching nontrivial example that is power is more than 2.
 Also there is answer that $D_4$ will work But I am not convincing with that as there are only 2 kind of elements in that Rotation and reflection 
Consider $(rs)^3$=rs and $(rs)^4=e$ which is suggested by that answer but $r^3s^3=r^3s$ which is not both same .

Comment: I know that But  I am not convincing with that answer.Please Help me

Comment: Why are you not convinced by that answer? I have edited it slightly to replace $i=0, 1$ with $i=6, 7$. You should work out why, in that question, these statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in $Q_8$, the Quaternion group!

Added: $Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ where $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$ and $ij=k$, $jk=i$, $ji=-k$, $ik=j$, $ki=-j$, $kj=-i$.

In this group $(a.b)^i=a^i.b^i$ holds for $i=4,5$. But $Q_8$ is non-Abelian, Since $ij \neq ji$

Comment: Can you suggest for which power this will hold?

Comment: $(a.b)^i=a^i.b^i$ holds for $i=4,5$ but $G$ is non Abelian

Comment: Note that this is a special case of what user1729 suggest in a comment to the duplicate answer, since the quaternion group has exponent $4$.

Comment: But in the OP the user ask "I searched for example ......". Thats what I mention!